# get method in WCF returns Null

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a wcf library and have 1 host and 2 clients connected to it.

Within my WCF I have code which stores a message sent to the WCF from client A:

```
 private string CustReady; //whether the customer is ready
```

and I have a get an set method for this, as follows

```
  public string sendReady(string s_Ready)
    {   
        CustReady = s_Ready;
    }

    //gets state of customer (POS)
    public string getReady()
    {
        return CustReady;
    }
```

Client A utilizes the sendReady method and passes in a string which is then stored in CustReady.  In client B the getReady method is fired when there is a button click and retrieves the string held inside the CustReady variable.  When I put a break point in my WCF around these 2 methods Client A stores the information correctly however when I press on the button on Client B it returns null. I was wondering if anyone knew why?

Thanks

Comment: How is your service configured for InstanceContextMode?  Chances are Client A and Client B are accessing different instances of the service.  If you can post your service code we can probably tell you more.

Comment: Hi Tim, I thought the same thing as you that they were accessing different instances of the service I will edit my post which will contain my service code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two clients are using two instances of the host so they do not share the variable. You must make the variable static or set the [InstanceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) of the [ServiceBehivorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.aspx) on the server to [InstanceContextMode.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) (if you do not set ConcurrencyMode to Multiple you can handle only one connection at a time to the service.)

```
  [ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single
  )]
  public class BehaviorService : IBehaviorService
  {
     //Snip
  }
```